# Does Groovy have object destructuring like Javascript?

Tags: groovy, destructuring

Does Groovy have object destructuring with multiple assignments like Javascript:

```
let options = {
  title: "Menu",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

let {title, width, height} = options;

alert(title);  // Menu
alert(width);  // 100
alert(height); // 200
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Groovy doesn't have JavaScript's object destructuring... It only has index based destructuring

https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_object_destructuring_with_multiple_assignment